# DisplayPort 1.2 Daisy Chain Third Monitor Not Working

Tags: multiple-monitors, displayport

I have:

- 3x [Dell 24" U2414H monitors](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?sku=860-BBCG)
- 1x [AMD Radeon R9 200 Series graphics card](http://www.asus.com/Graphics_Cards/R9270XDC2T2GD5/)

I am attempting to daisy chain the three monitors together to take advantage of multi-stream transport (MST). When I enable DisplayPort 1.2 mode on the first monitor in the chain, the second monitor gets its own desktop but the third monitor in the chain goes black and shows the standard "no input source". I also get [this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLWkK.png) as a result of enabling 1.2 on the monitors. Anyone have experience with getting all 3 monitors to work correctly?

Comment: Your monitors support the required resolution right?  You also have 1.2 supported cables.  Lots of "cheap" cables do not actually support daisy chaining.

Comment: > http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTcxMjI the linux 3.17 kernel **should** have a fix for this... i read it should have been rolled out in 3.16... but looks to be pushed back to 3.17... *(of which, the rc runs smoothly) Have you gotten the daisy chain to work with only 2 monitors? also are you using the proprietary ati drivers? http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86_64 your screen shot looks like ... you've made your linux look like windows... meh.. to each is his own.. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things to check:

- The similar U2515H needs to have DP 1.2 enabled, *except in the last monitor in the chain* which needs to have it disabled. Otherwise Multi-Stream Transport is going to be unreliable or nonfunctional.
- Your graphics card needs enough throughput on a single port to drive three monitors at whatever resolution you're tring to run them at.
  `xrandr --verbose` will tell you what monitors the driver detected, what their preferred resolutions and refresh rates are.

Answer (score 0):

I just bought some of these monitors too.

Check the setting in the monitor menu under Display Settings > Display 1.2 > Enable

Answer (score 0):

I had another issue: The frequency settings in Windows. They were set to 60Hz with interlacing. Had to choose 60Hz without interlacing in the advanced monitor settings.

Comment: It's "Interlacing".